# Handling missing modules errors in Node

Tags: node.js, cordova

I'm working on some cordova hooks that require shelljs. Now if a user doesn't have shelljs installed, they get this error message

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'shelljs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    ....
```

So this message is pretty ugly I want to provide a better message to the user. Is there anyway to prevent this message and then allow a custom message through `console.log`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap it in a try-catch:

```
var shelljs;
try {
  shelljs = require('shelljs');
} catch (ex) {
  console.log('ShellJS is required');
  process.exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Any way to get rid of this? `Hook failed with error code 1:`

Comment: Can you post the full output somewhere (especially error messages that come before that)? That alone doesn't tell much.

Comment: Well the output is just where the code exited on, or what file caused the exit